# WebStorm error message - use esversion 6

Tags: webstorm, jshint

WebStorm is showing the following error message:

`JSHint: 'let' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion': 6) ...`

In the Preferences -> Languages & Framework -> JavaScript menu I've selected the `ECMAScript 6` option and my `.jshintrc` file does contain the `"esversion": 6,` line.

I've tried the two most recent versions of the app (which are now 2016.3.6 and 2017.1.2) but to no avail.

I've also deleted the files in `~/Library/Application Support/WebStormXX` and
`~/Library/Preferences/WebStormXX` but nothing seems to have changed.

I'm using OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: error comes from *JShint*, so it has nothing to do with language version set in `Languages & Framework | JavaScript`. Please provide your `.jshintrc` and screenshot of `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint`

Comment: Hello, @lena. Thanks to your comment I was able to figure out what was wrong. The `Use config file` checkbox of the `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint` was not checked. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [@lena's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) comment I was able to figure out what was wrong. The `Use config file` checkbox of the `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint` was not checked so my `.jshintrc` was just being ignored.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have your own config file, you can enable `EcmaScript.next` in `Relaxing options` in in

> Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools |
>   JSHint

See this question [How-do-I-resolve-these-JSHint-ES6-errors](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000112510-How-do-I-resolve-these-JSHint-ES6-errors-?flash_digest=7f9a0f5de48b847a37ee71c787c0d42fa63f2234)

Answer (score -9):

I'd probably recommend a more feature rich editor like vim

Comment: This kind of made my day